# How to ASN.1 encode a map / dictionary?

Tags: java, smalltalk, pharo, asn.1, squeak

My ASN.1 library[1][2], in Java and Squeak/Pharo, supports sequences, sequence-of and mapped-sequence, as well as set, set-of and mapped-set. The missing collection type I wish to map is the dictionary, or map.

Are there any standard way of mapping a dictionary of key/value pairs to a robust ASN.1 encoding? Are there links to this common standard and/or examples of mapping a map/dictionary of key/value pairs? Perhaps an undiscovered SO discussion could be pointed to.

I believe I want a key/value representation of the ANY type, not use of a MappedSequence. The issue is self-description, the MappedSequence has a pre-defined set of Structure Elements, so ordering is important as the keys are implicitly used. I want more of a self-describing ANY type, which includes unordered key/value pairs. Does this make any sense? ;)

I am trying to create a generic object mapping, sort of an ANY type, but it would need the key/value pairs of the instance variables of said generic object. I wish to use language reflection, based on an encoded class name matching a language class, then generate an ASN.1 "ANY" type with the same structure, then us that type to decode the encoded object. I do not have a robust ANY type implemented, in either language implementation.

Thank you.

[1] - https://github.com/CallistoHouseLtd/ASN1

[2] - http://www.squeaksource.com/Cryptography/Cryptography-HenryHouse.113.mcz

Answer (score 3):

SNMP uses ASN.1 encoding and key-value pairs, so that could be a good starting point. [RFC 3416](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3416#section-3) defines the syntax as an ASN.1 module named `SNMPv2-PDU`.

`VarBind` is the key-value pair:

```
VarBind ::= SEQUENCE {
        name ObjectName,

        CHOICE {
            value          ObjectSyntax,
            unSpecified    NULL,    -- in retrieval requests 

                                    -- exceptions in responses
            noSuchObject   [0] IMPLICIT NULL,
            noSuchInstance [1] IMPLICIT NULL,
            endOfMibView   [2] IMPLICIT NULL
        }
    }
```

with `ObjectName` as key:

```
ObjectName ::= OBJECT IDENTIFIER
```

and `ObjectSyntax` as value:

```
ObjectSyntax ::= CHOICE {
      simple           SimpleSyntax,
      application-wide ApplicationSyntax }

SimpleSyntax ::= CHOICE {
      integer-value   INTEGER (-2147483648..2147483647),
      string-value    OCTET STRING (SIZE (0..65535)),
      objectID-value  OBJECT IDENTIFIER }

ApplicationSyntax ::= CHOICE {
      ipAddress-value        IpAddress,
      counter-value          Counter32,
      timeticks-value        TimeTicks,
      arbitrary-value        Opaque,
      big-counter-value      Counter64,
      unsigned-integer-value Unsigned32 }
```

A sequence of key-value pairs is `VarBindList`:

```
VarBindList ::= SEQUENCE (SIZE (0..max-bindings)) OF VarBind
```

An example of `VarBindList` in an SNMP packet ([BER-encoded](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3417#section-8)):

```
30|36                                  [SEQUENCE]
 30|10                                  [SEQUENCE]
  06|0a|2b 06 01 02 01 02 02 01 04 01    [OID] 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.4.1
  02|02|05 dc                            [INTEGER] 1500
 30|12                                  [SEQUENCE]
  06|0a|2b 06 01 02 01 02 02 01 05 01    [OID] 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5.1
  42|04|05 f5 e1 00                      [Gauge32] 100000000
 30|14                                  [SEQUENCE]
  06|0a|2b 06 01 02 01 02 02 01 06 01    [OID] 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.1
  04|06|53 74 72 69 6e 67                [OCTET STRING] "String"
```

Comment: I did not know the details of SNMP, though I have processed MIBs in the past - thank you for the illumination. This sparks the idea that I could define an ObjectStructure, with a SEQUENCE of InstanceVariableStructure key/value {Utf8String, ANY} SEQUENCES. Then, in respect of the following answer, use an ANY in my root message send structures (2 out of 5 of them) to hold the argument object graph that is encoded. At runtime use the ObjectStructure type to decode any ANY found.

ObjectStructure ::= SEQUENCE {

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is a direct equivalent of the Mapping data structure among the built-in ASN.1 types.

Can you use the `SET OF` container type holding a two-element `SEQUENCE` type representing the key-value pairs?  This won't save you automatically from duplicates though. You will have to insure the uniqueness of the keys in your code. Or you may want to look into the ASN.1 constraints in case you could use them to describe the uniqueness of the elements.

The `ANY` type is normally used to postpone type definition till the runtime. So that the receiving end could look elsewhere (see `ANY DEFINED BY`) and figure out what is coming in that `ANY` field. Then it could decode its contents based on the just obtained knowledge of the structure of the field being processed. This is mostly useful when you can't know all possible data types at the time of protocol design (e.g. it's the extensibility feature).

Comment: I see your point about duplicates but that matches my view that the encoding should not have to specify the constraints, I can let the system enforce that external to the structure definitions. I realize that means extra rules outside of te specification, yet here we are unable to express an arbitrary object in ASN.1, decades after the advent of OO. I like ASN.1 a lot, but there are weaknesses, left to the encapsulating program using this encoding. My feeling.

Is this how ANY works, then? The encapsulating program specifies at runtime. As the answer I posted, ANY will be an ObjectStructure.

Comment: The problem here is that ANY is part of the 1988 ASN.1 that was withdrawn in 1994.  If you used any version of ASN.1 from 1994 or later instead of the obsolete 1988 version, you would be using an open type (the replacement for ANY) which allows you to explicitly define a table of objects by which you can constrain the open type.

Comment: @PaulThorpe Is not it that ASN.1 `INFORMATION OBJECT CLASS` deprecates `ANY` in a backward-compatible way?

Comment: @ZZimbarra Just a minor note that using `ANY` does not imply departing from ASN.1 structure definitions. You are likely to have all your structures defined in ASN.1, but with `ANY` you are not nesting structures statically (e.g. at the time of ASN.1 spec design), rather let your decoder to find the right sub-structure from an open-ended collection of potential candidates for a field and plug it in at runtime.

Comment: @IlyaEtingof Modern ASN.1 replaces ANY (in a backward compatible manner) with open types which can be constrained in a manner fully understood unambiguously by ASN.1 compilers.  The ANY DEFINED BY that was removed from ASN.1 in 1994 did not have any way of defining the lookup table based on the component referenced by the ANY DEFINED BY.  Information Object Sets provide that capability while maintaining backward compatibility with the ANY and ANY DEFINED BY.  The 1988 version of ASN.1 was withdrawn (not deprecated) by both ITU-T and ISO in 1994.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps...
`

```
DeliverMessage ::= SEQUENCE {
    receiverID               INTEGER,
    selector                 UTF8STRING,
    arguments                SEQUENCE-OF ObjectStructure,
    answerID                 INTEGER,
    redirector               ObjectStructure }

ObjectStructure ::= SEQUENCE {
    className                UTF8STRING,
    instanceVariables        SEQUENCE-OF InstanceVariable }

InstanceVariable ::= SEQUENCE {
    instanceVariableName     UTF8STRING,
    value                    ANY }
```

`